# recaptcha v3 needs execution only or also verification for efficiency?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

> we recommend including reCAPTCHA verification on forms or actions as
>   well as in the background of pages for analytics.
>
> Note: You can execute reCAPTCHA as many times as you'd like with
>   different actions on the same page.
>   (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)

Based on this comment, should I be executing only the grecaptcha.execute function in the background of the page or do I also need to verify that the token is correct, also in the background?

This is in terms of improvement of the recaptcha v3 ML

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I have the same question along with others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470707/how-to-include-recaptcha-v3-in-the-background-of-pages